# PowerPoint VBA: Identify/replace Lao text in DokChampa font

Tags: vba, windows, fonts, ms-office, powerpoint

If I must boil my issue down to one question, it would be: in PowerPoint VBA, how can I identify lines in the DokChampa font?

I am working on some PowerPoint decks to teach myself Lao. When I type in Lao, Windows/Office appears to default to a font named “DokChampa”. I would like to use this in VBA to identify Lao text for some manipulations that I want to execute. Unfortunately, VBA reports the font of the Lao text as “Calibri”. If I try to use the Home > Editing > Replace > Replace Fonts dialog to replace DokChampa with Phetsarath OT, DokChampa does not appear in the list of fonts in the file.

Does anyone know:

- Why does PowerPoint not seem to identify the font properly?
- (How) Can I make Windows/Office default the font for Lao to Phetsarath OT rather than DokChampa, and would this help PowerPoint to correctly identify the font?
- In this condition, can I use VBA to replace DokChampa with Phetsarath OT?
- In this condition, can I use the Replace Font dialog to replace DokChampa with Phetsarath OT?
- I don’t want to cross-post, but is there a better forum for me to post an issue such as this?

I have included a screen shot that shows that I have text in DokChampa but that this font is missing from the Replace dropdown of the Font dialog.

This macro in the included PPTM (https://1drv.ms/p/s!Ak4T0TTB5WlkhI8goV0YpckjQrClDw?e=T0TBI9) also demonstrates the condition.

Sub showMe()

```
Dim nshp As Shape

For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If oshp.Name = "Content Placeholder 2" Then
                For Each oline In oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines
                    MsgBox oline.Font.Name & " : " & oline
                Next oline
            End If
        End If
    Next oshp
Next osld
```

End Sub

Microsoft Office 365 on Windows 10

[image: screen capture demonstrating issue]

Comment: Looks like I can check oline.LanguageID against 1108, but...

Comment: After this change, VBA reports the font of the line as Phetsarah OT but the visual font does not change and PowerPoint itself still reports the line as DokChampa. 
                        If oline.LanguageID = 1108 Then                             oline.Font.Name = "Phetsarath OT"

Comment: Just noting that oline.Font.NameFarEast of the line that is DokChampa but that PowerPoint says is Calibri reports as +mn-ea but changing this to "Phetsarath OT" doesn't seem to change it visually and I'm not sure if it should be some code instead of the font name.

Comment: I set all five to find out that I need to set NameComplexScript Rem oline.Font.Name = "Phetsarath OT"
Rem oline.Font.NameAscii = "Phetsarath OT"
oline.Font.NameComplexScript = "Phetsarath OT"
Rem oline.Font.NameFarEast = "Phetsarath OT"
Rem oline.Font.NameOther = "Phetsarath OT"

Comment: I am going to leave this unanswered in the hope that someone comments...

Answer (score 0):

This may help analyze what's going on. It may be that the font replace dialog only allows you to replace western font names but not Complex or FarEast font names. That does seem to be what's happening, or at least it's a possible explanation.

```
Sub FontsHaveManyNames()

Dim x As Long

With ActivePresentation.Fonts
    Debug.Print .Count
    For x = 1 To .Count
        Debug.Print x
        Debug.Print .Item(x).Name
        Debug.Print .Item(x).NameComplexScript
        Debug.Print .Item(x).NameFarEast
        Debug.Print .Item(x).NameOther

    Next
End With

End Sub
```